# Пропуск начала работает очень медленно

Tags: ffmpeg, видео, командная-строка

Чтобы вырезать кусок видео при помощи ffmpeg я использую опции `-ss` для указания начала и `-t` для указания длительности:

```
ffmpeg -i "smth.flv" -ss 42:47 -t 49 -vcodec h264 -acodec copy -format avi "smth.avi"
```

Проблема в том, что на обработку стартовых 42 минут тратится куча времени.

**Можно ли быстро перейти к нужному месту и отрезать интересующий кусок?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том, что `-ss` в приведённой команде стоит после input'ов.

Для того, чтобы пропуск произошёл быстро, надо ставить это параметр перед каждым `-i`:

```
ffmpeg -ss 42:47 -i "smth.flv" -t 49 -vcodec h264 -acodec copy -format avi "smth.avi"
```

Источник: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42639384/4928642