# ffmpeg получение crop данных

Tags: ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i "+file+" -ss 10 -t 20 -vf cropdetect -f null - 2>&1 | awk '/crop/ { print  $NF }' | tail -1
```

Кроп беру с 10 по 20 секунду. В данный момент попалось видео в котором с 10 - 20 секунду темный экран. Соответственно данные кропа неверные.

Убрать тайм и проверять целиком от начала и до конца, слишком ного времени уходит. Каким  образом возможно проверить не один отрезок, а скажем 3 с 10-20/200-210/3000-3010. Если на всех трех отрезках кроп выдаем, если нет, отдаем исходные.

Собственно как реализовать и имеется ли вариант по надежней?

В данный момент видео идет 4 часа, запустил на получение кропа. Не менее 20 секунд ожидаю, не выход как понимаю...

Comment: Не совсем по теме, но https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/813858/178988

Comment: Тоже самое, указан начало и конец. Это работает. Но чтобы исключить что на этом отрезке будет темный экран или черные полосы иначе нежели на другом отрезке. Необходимо указать еще один отрезок. Вопрос в том как указать в команде 2 или лучше 3 отрезка по котором необходимо смотреть...